# Disable Animation with Charts.js

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm having some trouble turning off the animation with charts.js.

This is my code:

```
var pieData = [
    {
        value: 30,
        color:"#F38630"
    },
    {
        value : 50,
        color : "#E0E4CC"
    },
    {
        value : 100,
        color : "#69D2E7"
    }    
];

var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData);
```

Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 153):

```
options: {
    animation: {
        duration: 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Much cleaner approach IMO than the undocumented `animation: false` trick. Setting `duration` to `0` stills allows to use the `options.animation.onComplete()` callback for custom drawings on the chart, when rendering has finished.

Answer (score 93):

```
var pieData = [{
    value: 30,
    color: "#F38630"
}, 
{
    value: 50,
    color: "#E0E4CC"
}, 
{
    value: 100,
    color: "#69D2E7"
}];

var pieOptions = {
    animation: false
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var myPie = new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData, pieOptions);
```

That should work ;)

Comment: Where is `options.animation` listed in the documentation? Neither http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html and http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html mention a boolean "`animation`"  property.

Comment: @Dai Do not compare 4 years old answer with current documentation.

Comment: but your answer does work with the current versions of ChartJS, that’s why I gave you an upvote.

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#:~:text=Disabling%20animation,setting%20the%20duration%20to%200%20.&text=Copied!

Answer (score 25):

Try this:

```
options: {
    animation: {
        duration: 0, // general animation time
    },
    hover: {
        animationDuration: 0, // duration of animations when hovering an item
    },
    responsiveAnimationDuration: 0, // animation duration after a resize
}
```

Answer (score 16):

According to the docs (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/performance.html#disable-animations) here is the way to completely disable animations:

```
new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        animation: {
            duration: 0 // general animation time
        },
        hover: {
            animationDuration: 0 // duration of animations when hovering an item
        },
        responsiveAnimationDuration: 0 // animation duration after a resize
    }
});
```

Answer (score 15):

Hi following 3 options works for the disabling the animation

1)Disable animation:

```
var myLine = Chart.Line(ctx, {
        data: lineChartData,
        options: {
           animation: false,
         }
        });
```

2)Reduce animation duration for 0

```
var myLine = Chart.Line(ctx, {
        data: lineChartData,
        options: {   
            animation: {
                duration: 0,
            },
         });
```

3)Global Option:

```
 Chart.defaults.global.animation = false;
    var myLine = Chart.Line(ctx, {
        data: lineChartData,
        options: {
         }
       });
```

Answer (score 10):

To prevent reading all of the accepted answer that answers that particular example, to disable animation in chart js:

Pass an object in your options when initialising the particular chart type and use the following key/value pair: `animation: false`. e.g. `myChart.Bar(myCanvas, {animation:false});`

Answer (score 9):

This can also be done globally:

`Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 0`

Via: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#animation-configuration

Answer (score 7):

```
options{
    animation: false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
    chartOption = {
        animation:{
            duration: 0
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who can't disable animations when they use:

```
const chartOptions = {
  animation: {
    duration: 0,
  },
};
```

Give the Chart a **fixed** height. If the parent element is responsive it may cause the chart to re-render and make it seem as if animations are not disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I tried above all solutions but doesn't make any changes in my angular 14 project. so i found another working solution.
add height and width but use 'important' also.

```
        <canvas style="height: 400px!important;width: 400px!important;"></canvas>
```