# Formatting the default ease animation in Chart.js

Tags: reactjs

How can i stop the easing animation of the chartjs in react. I just want a still graph rather than having it increase gradually from 0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Animation with Charts.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389341/disable-animation-with-charts-js)

Comment: no,it is still not working. I just want the chart to be a still picture, but when the DOM loads, the chart datasets or bars transition from 0 on both axis to their corresponding values